# Reusable button with datatrigger in Silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

In my Windows phone 8.1 silverlight application, the user can select a date and move to the next or previous day. I would like to add the ability to gray the button to select the next day when this day is in the future (because it has no sense in my application).

For that I created a style to define the right arrow button (and I also have the same for the left arrow, there may also have a better way to do it?).

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="arrowRight" BasedOn="{StaticResource RemoveButtonBorderStyle}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        Margin="2,6,2,2"
                        Fill="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}"
                        Data="M0,0L496.000005990267,315 0,630z">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I applied in on my button like this :

```
  <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="2"  Command="{Binding NextMonthCommand}"  Style="{StaticResource arrowRight}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Day,Converter={StaticResource IsNextDayInTheFutureConverter }}" Value="True">
                                <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                                <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </ec:DataTrigger>
                            <ec:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Day,Converter={StaticResource IsNextDayInTheFutureConverter }}" Value="False">
                                <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                <ec:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </ec:DataTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

My problem is that I can have more than one button acting like this. In another page of my application, the user can select a month, and if the month is in the future, I want to disable the button.
What I do now, is copy paste the datatrigger part and change the binding from Day to Month but it doesn't realy feel right to me.
Is there another,better way to do ?

[image: My control]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an approach with Style converter? Say we add custom `Converter`:

```
public class ArrowBtnStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public Style EnabledStyle { get; set; }
   public Style DisabledStyle { get; set; }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      //put your conversion logic here instead of that nonsense.
      //You can also check 'parameter' to switch between day/month/etc modes
      return value != null ? EnabledStyle : DisabledStyle;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

And then use it in XAML. Notice that `BasedOn` for both styles uses you arrow style.

```
<local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter x:Key="arrowStyleConverter">
    <local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter.EnabledStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource arrowRight}">
            <!-- You don't actually need those default values set explicitly.
                 I just leave them here to show that we could have some more options -->    
            <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />-->
        </Style>
    </local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter.EnabledStyle>
    <local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter.DisabledStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource arrowRight}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />
        </Style>
    </local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter.DisabledStyle>
</local:ArrowBtnStyleConverter>
```

After that, we just bind the Style of our Button. Again, notice the use of converter parameter. With it you can have single converter wich changes logic based on input (day, month, year, etc.), you just have to check parameter in converter code.

```
<Button Style="{Binding Day, Converter={StaticResource arrowStyleConverter}, ConverterParameter=day}" />
<Button Style="{Binding Month, Converter={StaticResource arrowStyleConverter}, ConverterParameter=month}" />
```